# Is it possible to create Emulators for specific Android mobile requirement

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin, android-emulator

I want to create the Android Emulator of the given device using Android studio or Genymotion.

How can I do that for below screenshot?

[image]

Comment: I think you can only create AVD using options provided in the link https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds , did you give this a try

Comment: @JitendarM - Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

open android studio to to AVD Manager click `Create Virtual Device` in bottom left corner click `New Hardware Profile` and here you can create device with custom requirements.